# war file application failed to start on tomcat

Tags: spring, ubuntu, vps, lamp, tomcat9

dear friend. The developers, I have a problem with the deployment of my WAR file. I manually added it using FileZilla FTP to the web app. It is displayed on the list of applications in the manager app, but it is stopped. When I try to start it, it doesn't want to start, and it shows me these error messages
FAILED - The application for context path [/bolight] could not be started
FAILED - Exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/bolight]]] was encountered[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udGIa.png)

I want a solution the rather to start the application on tomcat app manager thanks in advance